# Compare the dataframe of each file read from s3

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large number of files in aws s3 folder. I want to read the file from each folder in python and compare and merge dataframe such that if the particular column value is similar in another dataframe add the corresponding column value to list and all other to next row

For example : dataframe df1

```
A               B
books          [book1, book2, book3]
animal         [animal1, animal2, animal3]
place          [place1 , place2, place3]

dataframe df2

A .          B
name        [name1, name2, name3]
animal      [animal 5, animal 6]
```

then the result should be: df

```
A             B
books          [book1, book2, book3]
animal         [animal1, animal2, animal3, animal5, animal6]
place          [place1 , place2, place3]
name        [name1, name2, name3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Join all DataFrames by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate values of `B` with flatten list of lists in lambda function in list comprehension:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

f = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
df3 = df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df3)
        A                                                B
0   books                            [book1, book2, book3]
1  animal  [animal1, animal2, animal3, animal 5, animal 6]
2   place                         [place1, place2, place3]
3    name                            [name1, name2, name3]
```

Or:

```
#slow solution in large data
df = df.groupby('A', sort=False)['B'].sum().reset_index()
```